# Push-in splice - What is this model?

Tags: electrical, connectors, wago

This model was likely common 25 years ago, in Europe (France). I don't know the brand and cannot find any reference based on pictures.

[image]

The plastic case is fully transparent, no levers, only a slat. The top of the case is trapezoid. I'm not sure of the markings, perhaps 600M IDEAL 85.

---

I've two questions for someone who already saw this beast:

- What are the brand, and model if possible.
- How do you properly unplug the wires? (I've seen advice to just turn the wire until it is loose...)

Comment: If not short of wire, a pair of wire cutters will remove the wires fast, with the power off.  There might be a tiny slot/opening to push a tool/tiny screwdriver in, to release the wire/s.  Somethings do have a bad design when it comes to repairs or a use once only design.  Have a machine with one bolt/nut in a bad place to undo.  Most times it is faster to use a torch to cut the nut off.

Comment: @crip659: Thanks. I cannot check at the moment, but I remember seeing a tiny hole next to the inputs for the wires. Cutting the wires is not possible as I need to understand the cause of a voltage leakage, and I'll likely have to connect/unconnected several times different portions. After it is repaired, I plan to change the connectors for something reusable.

Comment: I would have reusable ones handy in case those are single use.  We have push in connectors on outlets/switches in the US, but on the cheaper ones they are/should only be used once.  Good electricians don;t like them, unless being paid to change the wires to the screws.

Comment: The brand is all-but-certainly **Ideal®**, based on the marking, and the fact that Ideal is a maker of wire connection products including some push-in wire connectors; but I have no idea exactly what they commonly sold in France 25 years ago. I preferred wire-nuts (Marrettes) which they also make to these things when the version of these things they sold here was common in the USA.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That appears to be an early version of the product Ideal® currently calls **In-Sure Push In** (in English, anyway) and the current 88/87 model numbers suggest that 85 is a plausible model number. Or perhaps 35, given the current 33, 34 & 39.

[image]

600M is probably a misreading of the V for M in the 600Volt rating.

[image]

*Image Source: https://www.idealind.com/us/en/shop/product-type/connectors/push-on.html no endorsement implied.* Possibly the France version of their site has the exact match, or possibly the old ones are no longer made in exactly that style/model number. The 34 instructions for wire removal are twist and pull, and not to re-use on stranded wire at all, and to re-strip solid wire, so moving immediately to a "removable-without-damage" lever type would be advisable rather than reusing these. The 88 instructions don't mention removal at all.

Comment: Thanks for all the useful details. My model seems older than the Internet in the end. You must be right for 600V.

Comment: The internet is fairly old, (quite a bit more than 25 years)  the stuff that companies show on their websites, on the other hand, has a very sort expiration time, in many/most cases.